# Dot tree Graphviz

Tags: windows, graphviz, dot

Please help me.I want some code in dot language that I can use with Graphviz so I can print something that looks as much as possible to this family tree.I need this for a college assignment.I have tried for days but I can figure it out myself.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - what have you tried so far ? Unfortunately SO is not a code writing service - i suggest you study the graphviz documentation on the https://www.graphviz.org/ website and see what examples there are you can use.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337904/how-to-implement-grandchild-enkel1-into-family-tree-with-graphviz/56341677?r=SearchResults&s=54%7C21.8861#56341677)